# Setting object keys from variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in javascript is it possible to construct an object literal with expressions evaluating to strings for property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783403/in-javascript-is-it-possible-to-construct-an-object-literal-with-expressions-eva)

I am having a problem setting object keys and values from variables, if I set just the key or just the value from a variable it works fine if I set them both from variables it does not work.

This works fine

```
 $(":input").change(function () { 

    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var currentval = $(this).attr('value');

    $.post("/inside/update.php", {
        "profile_age":currentval 
    });
});
```

This configuration does not work

```
$(":input").change(function () { 

    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var currentval = $(this).attr('value');

    $.post("/inside/update.php", {
        currentId:currentval 
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI, there is no JSON in your code. You are dealing with JavaScript *object literals*.

Comment: soz bit of a novice and first time poster

Comment: No worries, just pointing it out! JSON looks similar to JS object literals, so the confusing is understandable (and in fact pretty common (unfortunately)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var options = {};
options[currentId] = currentval; 
$.post("/inside/update.php", options);
```